# Will Support Vector Machine always return linear weights and bias?

Tags: classification, svm, kernel-trick

This code create the linear bondary between two classes.

```
% Töm
clear all
close all
clc

x1 = randn(50, 2);
x2 = 10 + randn(50, 2);
x = [x1; x2];
y = [linspace(1, 1, 50)'; linspace(-1, -1, 50)'];

% Träna en linjär SVM med quadprog
C = 10;
H = (y*y').*(x*x');
H = H + 10*eye(size(H));
f = -ones(size(y));
Aeq = y';
beq = 0;
lb = zeros(size(y));
ub = C*ones(size(y));
%alpha = qp([], H, f, Aeq, beq, lb, ub)
%alpha = qp([], H, f, [], [], [], [], [], [eye(size(H)); -eye(size(H)); Aeq; -Aeq], [ub; -lb; beq; -beq])
[alpha, solution] = quadprog(H, f, [eye(size(H)); -eye(size(H)); Aeq; -Aeq], [ub; -lb; beq; -beq]);

% Beräkna vikterna för linjär SVM
w = sum(repmat(alpha.*y,1,size(x,2)).*x,1);

% Hitta stödvektorer
tol = 1e-4;
sv_idx = find(alpha>tol);
b = mean(y(sv_idx)-x(sv_idx,:)*w');

% Plotta träningsdata och linjär SVM
figure;
scatter(x(y==-1,1),x(y==-1,2),'r');
hold on
scatter(x(y==1,1),x(y==1,2),'g');
h = ezplot(@(x2,x3) w(1)*x2+w(2)*x3+b);
set(h,'Color','k','LineWidth',2);
ylim([min(x(:, 1)) max(x(:, 1))]);
xlim([min(x(:, 2)) max(x(:, 2))]);
legend('Röda','Gröna','SVM-gräns', 'location', 'northwest');
grid on
```

[image]

This creates a nonlinear boundary between two classes.

```
% close
close all
clear all

% Skapa träningsdata
x1 = randn(50, 2);
x2 = 10 + randn(50, 2);
x = [x1; x2];
y = [linspace(1, 1, 50)'; linspace(-1, -1, 50)'];

% Träna en icke-linjär SVM med quadprog och RBF-kärna
C = 10;
sigma = 1;
n = size(x,1);
K = zeros(n,n);
for i = 1:n
    for j = 1:n
        K(i,j) = exp(-norm(x(i,:)-x(j,:))^2/(2*sigma^2));
    end
end
H = (y*y').*K;
H = H + 10*eye(size(H));
f = -ones(size(y));
Aeq = y';
beq = 0;
lb = zeros(size(y));
ub = C*ones(size(y));
%alpha = qp([], H, f, Aeq, beq, lb, ub);
[alpha, solution] = quadprog(H, f, [eye(size(H)); -eye(size(H)); Aeq; -Aeq], [ub; -lb; beq; -beq]);

% Beräkna vikterna för icke-linjär SVM
w = zeros(1,size(x,2));
for i = 1:n
    w = w + alpha(i)*y(i)*x(i,:);
end
w

% Hitta stödvektorer
tol = 1e-4;
sv_idx = find(alpha>tol);
b = mean(y(sv_idx)-K(sv_idx,:)*alpha);
b

% Vektor för hyperplanet - Alternativ
w = (alpha .* y)' * x
b = mean(y - K*(alpha .* y))

% Plotta träningsdata och icke-linjär SVM
figure;
hold on;
scatter(x(y==-1,1),x(y==-1,2),'r');
scatter(x(y==1,1),x(y==1,2),'g');
[x1_grid,x2_grid] = meshgrid(linspace(min(x(:,1))-10,max(x(:,1))+10,100),linspace(min(x(:,2))-10,max(x(:,2))+10,100));
X_grid = [x1_grid(:),x2_grid(:)];
K_grid = zeros(size(X_grid,1),n);
for i = 1:size(X_grid,1)
    for j = 1:n
        K_grid(i,j) = exp(-norm(X_grid(i,:)-x(j,:))^2/(2*sigma^2));
    end
end
y_grid = K_grid*alpha;
y_grid = reshape(y_grid,size(x1_grid));
contour(x1_grid,x2_grid,y_grid);
grid on
```

[image]

This also create a nonlinear boundary between two classes.

```
% Töm
clear all
close all
clc

% Träningsdata
x1 = randn(50, 2);
x2 = 10 + randn(50, 2);
X = [x1; x2];
y = [linspace(1, 1, 50)'; linspace(-1, -1, 50)'];

% Polynomisk kärna
d = d;
K = (1 + X*X').^d;

% Kvadratiskt optimeringsproblem
H = (y*y').*K;
H = H + 10*eye(size(H));
f = -ones(size(y));
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = y';
beq = 0;
lb = zeros(size(y));
ub = ones(size(y)) * Inf;
%alpha = quadprog(H, f, A, b, Aeq, beq, lb, ub);
[alpha, solution] = quadprog(H, f, [eye(size(H)); -eye(size(H)); Aeq; -Aeq], [ub; -lb; beq; -beq]);

% Vektor för hyperplanet
w = (alpha .* y)' * X;
b = mean(y - K*(alpha .* y));

% Plotta datapunkterna och hyperplanet
x1 = linspace(min(X(:,1)), max(X(:,1)), 100);
x2 = linspace(min(X(:,2)), max(X(:,2)), 100);
[X1, X2] = meshgrid(x1, x2);
XX = [X1(:) X2(:)];
KK = (1 + XX*X').^d;
decision_values = KK*(alpha .* y) - b;
decision_values = reshape(decision_values, size(X1));
contour(x1, x2, decision_values, [0 0], 'LineWidth', 2)
hold on
scatter(X(:,1), X(:,2), 50, y, 'filled')
colormap('cool')
colorbar
xlabel('X_1')
ylabel('X_2')
title(sprintf('Polynomial kernel, degree %d', d))
```

[image]

What they all have in common is that $w$ is a $n$ long array, in this case **2** and $b$ is a scalar.

**Question:**

If I only want to use my weights $w$ and bias $b$ to classify the data, can I create for example a nonlinear curve from only $w$ and $b$ that are going to represent the boundary?

In this case I'm not using $w$ when I'm using a kernel. The array $w$ is only used when I have a linear kernel.

But I want to create a nonlinear boundary in form of an equation. Is that possible?